# Pandas Merge with interpolation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes df1 and df2

**df1**

[image: Date/Time S 1/1/2012 0:00 7.51 1/1/2012 1:00 7.28 1/1/2012 2:00 6.75 1/1/2012 3:00 7.80 1/1/2012 4:00 8.18 1/1/2012 5:00 0.00 1/1/2012 6:00 5.00]

```
Date/Time   S
1/1/2012 0:00   7.51
1/1/2012 1:00   7.28
1/1/2012 2:00   6.75
1/1/2012 3:00   15.00
1/1/2012 4:00   8.18
1/1/2012 5:00   0.00
1/1/2012 6:00   5.00
```

**df2**

[image]

```
 S  Val
3.00    30
4.00    186
5.00    406
6.00    723
7.00    1169
8.00    1704
9.00    2230
10.00   2520
11.00   2620
12.00   2700
```

I would like to merged the two dataframes with interpolated val.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['S'], right_on=['S'])
```

For example:
df1 'S' column will be lookup value, and column 'S' in df2 will be lookupRange, and the outputRange will be column 'Val'.

The value below 3 and above 12 will be 0.

The output should be as shown below, How can i achieve this in pandas?. or any alternative solution in python other then looping much appreciated.

**Output**

[image]

```
Date/Time   S   Val
1/1/2012 0:00   7.51    1441.9
1/1/2012 1:00   7.28    1318.8
1/1/2012 2:00   6.75    1057.5
1/1/2012 3:00   15.00   0.0
1/1/2012 4:00   8.18    1798.7
1/1/2012 5:00   0.00    0.0
1/1/2012 6:00   5.00    406.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df2` is sorted by column `S`, you can do:

```
tmp = df1.assign(tmp=df1.S.apply(np.floor)).merge(df2.assign(tmp2=(df2.Val.shift(-1) - df2.Val)), how='outer', left_on='tmp', right_on='S')
tmp.loc[tmp.Val.isna(), 'S_x'] = 0
tmp['Val'] = (tmp['S_x'] - tmp['S_y'].fillna(0)) * tmp['tmp2'].fillna(1) + tmp['Val'].fillna(0)

print(tmp[['Date/Time', 'S_x', 'Val']].dropna().sort_values(by='Date/Time').rename(columns={'S_x': 'S'}))
```

Prints:

```
       Date/Time      S      Val
0  1/1/2012 0:00   7.51  1441.85
1  1/1/2012 1:00   7.28  1318.80
2  1/1/2012 2:00   6.75  1057.50
3  1/1/2012 3:00  15.00     0.00
4  1/1/2012 4:00   8.18  1798.68
5  1/1/2012 5:00   0.00     0.00
6  1/1/2012 6:00   5.00   406.00
```